# how to assign values to textfields which are created using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Am creating one application for that i need add fields dynamically so i used jquery.now in that text fields i need to retrieve the values from database and assign to that fields.

how to implement that.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

      (function($){
           $countForms = 1;
           $.fn.addForms = function(){
            var myform = "<table>"+
             "  <tr>"+
             "     <td>Pid:</td>"+
             "     <td><input type='text' name='id["+$countForms+"]'></td>"+
             "     <td>Pname:</td>"+
             "     <td><textarea name='name["+$countForms+"]'></textarea></td>"+
             "     <td>Pfee:</td>"+
             "     <td><input type='text' name='amount["+$countForms+"]'></td>"+
             "     <td><button>remove</button></td>"+
             "  </tr>"+
             "</table>";

             myform = $("<div>"+myform+"</div>");
             $("button", $(myform)).click(function(){ $(this).parent().parent().remove(); });

             $(this).append(myform);
             $countForms++;
      };
})(jQuery);     

$(function(){
    $("#mybutton").bind("click", function(){
        $("#container").addForms();
    });
});
```

Comment: What have you tried? If you want this to occur in response to a click you'll want to use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) (or one of its shortcut methods) to call some PHP. (Are you asking us to guess the structure of your database to provide an appropriate SELECT statement and the PHP code needed to run it, or...?)

Comment: am creating fields dynamically...i need to display values in that fields by retrieving db...